# Using DLL in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, unmanaged

I´m trying to use a old C DLL in a C# windows forms app.  Seems like i´m using the wrong datatype for the output parameter.

DLL source code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec (dllexport)
#endif

EXPORT INT CALLBACK Complemento (LPSTR) ;
EXPORT INT CALLBACK MatchCode (LPSTR, LPSTR, LPSTR, LPSTR);
```

c# DLL Export

```
[DllImport(
    @"<MYDIR>Fonetica.dll",
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int MatchCode(
    String n,
    String s,
    String e,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] out String retorno);
```

C# DLL usage code

```
String match = String.Empty;

MatchCode(pefi.Nome, String.Empty, String.Empty, out match);
```

The tree first parameters are input and the last one is an output.

I´m receiving this exception:

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.String..ctor(SByte* value)
       at System.StubHelpers.CSTRMarshaler.ConvertToManaged(IntPtr cstr)
       at WFMatchCode.Form1.MatchCode(String n, String s, String e, String& retorno)
       at WFMatchCode.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\computecnica.alexand\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WFMatchCode\WFMatchCode\Form1.cs:line 91
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at WFMatchCode.Program.Main() in c:\users\computecnica.alexand\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WFMatchCode\WFMatchCode\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Your C dll seems weird. How are people to know what is input and what is output? The first three parameters should be LPCSTR at least. And the output parameter is missing an parameter how long the array is that can be written too. What would you expect the marshalling to pass to this function as an ouput parameter? How large should the char array be?

Comment: @alexandre Passing `out string` is done through the use of a `StringBuilder`. Search around for pinvoke `StringBuilder` and you will find plenty of examples.

Comment: @nvoigt Thanks a lot but this sourcecode is 13 years old and I don´t want to change it... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
[DllImport( @"Fonetica.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int MatchCode(String n, String s, String e, StringBuilder retorno);
```

You then **must** pass a StringBuilder that has enough capacity to take whatever gets written to it. The same way you must pass an array that's large enough in C:

```
var capacity = 1000; // change this to whatever you need
var buffer = new StringBuilder(capacity);

var result = MatchCode("test", "test", "test", buffer);

var output = buffer.ToString();
```

Comment: It is correct... But I do *hate* `var` in this examples of code :-) (in truth only the `var output` and the `var result`)